# Core Data | Relationship with 2 inverses

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, relationship

I have an entity Team and an entity Match.
In entity Match I created relationships "team1" and "team2" :

[image]

In entity Team I would like to create a relationship "matches" to get all the matches played by a team :

[image]

Of course, my team can be the "team1" for some matches and "team2" for other matches.
How would you do this ? Thanks

Comment: You get Core Data wrong. I recommend to do at least one tutorial. [There are plenty](https://www.google.de/search?q=core+data+tutorial+swift+3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=aK9aWIqMIYfe8geUloyoBw)

Comment: Is it important to know which is "team1" and which is "team2", or is it enough to know that there were two teams?

Comment: @TomHarrington In fact I just want to get all matches for a given team so Yes this is important

Comment: @shallowThought I don't get it, I know what I'm doing is wrong and should not work, I just wanted to illustrate my example. I'm looking for a way to do this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is wrong. Do do not setup entries in the model, like `team1` and `team2`. The model is like a construction plan for the Core Data stack to setup the database, create and handle `NSManagedObjects` and its subclasses.

You should setup an `Entity` called `Team` in your model and fill it with entries like `team1` later on using Core Data (programmatically).

The model will look something like this:

[image]

Relationships might be easier to understand using the `Graph` view of the model:

[image]

The topic is to broad to go into detail. I recommend to follow a tutorial first.

Comment: This is very clear, You are right I was going on the wrong way, Thanks.
I created a relationship to-many "teams" in Entity Match and I set count minimum 2 / count maximum 2. And I created a relationship also to-many "matches" in Entity Team